# How to authenticate a Python script on Google AppEngine to use Google Firebase?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, firebase, firebase-authentication

Google has provided nice examples for Node.js, Android and iOS authentication of clients to connect to Firebase to use Firebase Realtime Databases - but how does one connect via Python from a Google AppEngine app to a Firebase Realtime Database and authenticate properly?

Answer (score 5):

Here are the steps we took to get this working.

(1) First you need a Firebase Secret. 
After you have a project in Firebase, then click Settings. Then click Database and choose to create a secret.  [image: settings]

Copy your secret. It will go into your code later.

[image: secret]

(2) You need your firebase URL. 
It will have the format like this: https://.firebaseio.com
Copy this too.

(3) Get a Firebase REST API for Python. 
We used this one: https://github.com/benletchford/python-firebase-gae
Navigate to above your lib directory and run this command which will place the firebase code into your lib directory:

```
git clone http://github.com/benletchford/python-firebase-gae lib/firebase
```

(4) In your "main.py" file (or whatever you are using) add this code:

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor
vendor.add('lib')

from firebase.wrapper import Firebase

FIREBASE_SECRET = 'YOUR SECRET FROM PREVIOUS STEPS'
FIREBASE_URL = 'https://[…].firebaseio.com/'
```

(5) Add this code to the MainHandler (assuming you are using AppEngine):

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        fb = Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'users.json', FIREBASE_SECRET)

        new_user_key = fb.post({
            "job_title": "web developer",
            "name": "john smith",
        })
        self.response.write(new_user_key)
        self.response.write('<br />')

        new_user_key = fb.post({
            "job_title": "wizard",
            "name": "harry potter",
        })
        self.response.write(new_user_key)
        self.response.write('<br />')

        fb = Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'users/%s.json' % (new_user_key['name'], ), FIREBASE_SECRET)
        fb.patch({
            "job_title": "super wizard",
            "foo": "bar",
        })

        fb = Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'users.json', FIREBASE_SECRET)
        self.response.write(fb.get())
        self.response.write('<br />')
```

Now when you navigate to your Firebase Realtime Database, you should see entries for Harry Potter as a user and others.

Comment: Where do you get the secret from?  I cant find that option.

Comment: @marciokoko It is the first step: In Firebase, then click Settings (the gear button) then click the Database tab, then choose to create a secret.

Comment: @marciokoko I just tried it. The location is still there.

Comment: OH!  I was going to the left hand side bar "Database" link instead of the top tab!  Thanks so much!

Comment: @Praxiteles I tried this, however it only will post the john smith entry. It will then throw an error for me: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'`

This is from the first `self.response.write(new_user_key)`

Comment: @DarkMatter Are you running under Google App Engine - or just running from the command line or terminal? If you are not running in App Engine, if you change the self.response.write to a print statement - does that work for you?

Comment: WHere is this database secret? I cannot find a database section within options.

Comment: I found the correct place. The path is: `Settings>Project Settings>Service Accounts>Database`. However, as noted above, this seems to be deprecated and we are suggested to use some kind of SDKs, but for whatever I can see it looks like they do not have a SDK for Realtime DB for Python. DOH.